# Transform HTML grab class and inner string in Sublime Text with Regex

Tags: regex, html-parsing, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm well aware of the dangers of [parsing HTML with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/340688) but I'm in a pickle and need to speed things up! I have this code block:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1"><i class="fc-icon-letterpress-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">This design is letterpressed onto the finest quality salvaged paper made here in the USA.</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1"><i class="fc-icon-madeinusa-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">We work hard to be able to say that this product is proudly created right here in the USA.</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1"><i class="fc-icon-cotton-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">This product is made from tree-free paper sourced from salvaged cotton from the textile industry.</div>
</div>
```

And I need it to be transformed to this:

```
letterpress-circle, "This design is letterpressed onto the finest quality salvaged paper made here in the USA.";
madeinusa-circle, "We work hard to be able to say that this product is proudly created right here in the USA.";
cotton-circle, "This product is made from tree-free paper sourced from salvaged cotton from the textile industry.";
```

Preferably with one regular expression, in sublime text

This is what I have so far.

```
.+i class=\"fc-icon-(.+)\".+
$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I landed on:

```
<div class=\"row\">
    <div class=\"span1\"><i class=\"fc-icon-(.+)\"></i>
    </div>
    <div class=\"span4\">(.+)</div>
</div>
```